# Im getting a element intercepted exception in robot framework, while im trying to click on a menu bar in the web application

Tags: robotframework

my code:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element  //span[contains(text(),'Transactions ')]    timeout=60s
sleep  3
Mouse Over  //span[contains(text(),'Transactions ')]
click Element  //span[contains(text(),'Transactions ')]
```

Output:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: 
Element <span style="font-size:15px">...</span> is not clickable at point 
    (73, 411). Other element would receive the click: <span style="font- 
    size:15px">...</span>
   (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

Source code:

```html
<li class="sub-menu  dcjq-parent-li">
  <a href="#" class="hvr-bounce-to-right-sidebar-parent dcjq- 
                     parent">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" style="font- 
                                                           size:20px"></span>
    <span style="font-size:15px">Procurement</span>
    <span style="padding:0 0 0 91px;">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right">
      </i>
    </span>
    <span class="fa dcjq-icon"></span>
  </a>
<li class="sub-menu  dcjq-parent-li">
  <a href="#" class="hvr-bounce-to-right-sidebar-parent dcjq- 
                     parent">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" style="font- 
                                                       size:20px"></span>
    <span style="font-size:15px">Transactions </span>
    <span style="padding:0 0 0 85px;">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right">
      </i>
    </span>
    <span class="fa dcjq-icon"></span></a>
```

Here im trying to click on the text of 'span' tag, 'Transaction', but element is getting clicked on 'Procurement' text.

Comment: In my experience getting this error really means there's an element overlaying the target one in the rendered state of the DOM. Try targeting a sibling one, or the parent `<a>` or `<li>` and see will it work.

Comment: No it doesnt work, i have used parent tag as well, but still it doesnt work, the problem is with the 'Mouse over keyword', for ex: if im using a mouse over, on Transactions, the cursor is pointing on 'Procurement', i have checked the same case with other link texts in the menu bar as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, not sure if it is correct.

Code:

```
   Wait Until Page Contains Element   //div/ul/li[7]/a[@href='#']   timeout=10s
   Wait Until Element Is Visible  //div/ul/li[7]/a[@href='#']    timeout=10s
   Set Focus To Element                
              //span[contains(text(),'Transactions')]/parent::a[@href='#']
   Simulate Event   //div/ul/li[7]/a/span[contains(text(),'Transactions ')]   click
```